# How to generate a 26-character hex string that equals to 106 bits and ((53 Ones - 53 Zeros) in binary)

Tags: vb.net, binary, hex

I am looking for a way to generate a hexadecimal string that equals out to 106 bits, more specifically fifty three 1's and fifty three 0's after each hex char is converted to binary and added together. I'd like to keep it as random as possible considering the parameters of the request. How would I go about keeping an eye on the construction of the string so that it equals out the way I want?

For example:

```
(a8c05779f8934b14ce96f8aa93) =
(1010 1000 1100 0000 0101 0111 0111 1001 1111 1000 1001 0011 0100
 1011 0001 0100 1100 1110 1001 0110 1111 1000 1010 1010 1001 0011)
```

Comment: Yes sorry, the last two come from half the 27th characters binary value. Last 2 digits. 1 = 0001 so 01 making it 106. the other half of the binary is used on another string which is used as a hash/checksum for the 106 bits.

Comment: So what do you want to do with the last two bits? They don't fit in the 26 character string.

Comment: Is there a way to use just use the last 2 digits of the binary value for the 27 hex character?

Comment: Yes, I added that to my answer.

Comment: Too bad I can't choose both answers. They both work to generate the string equal to 52 of each in bin.  I might have to go with guffa's though. with the 27 characters bits stored in the buf it is handy and further along. Thanks again you guys. Super fast responses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hex string Gen with binary value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351645/hex-string-gen-with-binary-value)

Comment: How could one solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place 52 ones randomly in a 104 bit number by keeping track of how many ones has been placed already and calculate the probability that the next digit should be one. The first digit always has 1/2 probability (52/104), then the second digit has 51/103 or 52/103 probability depending on what the first digit was, and so on.

Put the bits in a buffer, and when it is full (four bits), that makes a hexadecimal digit that you can add to the string:

```
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim bin As New StringBuilder()
Dim buf As Integer = 0, bufLen As Integer = 0, left As Integer = 52
For i As Integer = 104 To 1 Step -1
  buf <<= 1
  If rnd.Next(i) < left Then
    buf += 1
    left -= 1
  End If
  bufLen += 1
  If bufLen = 4 Then
    bin.Append("0123456789abcdef"(buf))
    bufLen = 0
    buf = 0
  End If
Next
Dim b As String = bin.ToString()
```

---

To make a 106 bit value, change these lines:

```
Dim buf As Integer = 0, bufLen As Integer = 0, left As Integer = 53
For i As Integer = 106 To 1 Step -1
```

The resulting string is still 26 characters, the two extra bits are in the `buf` variable. It has a value between `0` and `3` that you can use to create the 27th character, however that is done.

---

To add a 22 bit hash to the string, you can use code like this:

```
bin.Append("048c"(buf))
Dim b As String = bin.ToString()

Dim m As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed
Dim hash As Byte() = m.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(b))

'replace first two bits in hash with bits from buf
hash(0) = CByte(hash(0) And &H3F Or (buf * 64))
'append 24 bits from hash
b = b.Substring(0, 26) + BitConverter.ToString(hash, 0, 3).Replace("-", String.Empty)
```

Comment: So I converted this to VB and I get an error and "  If (Rnd.Next(i) < left) Then  " its says next is not a member of single? Any idea?

Comment: @AdamGrolli: Sorry, I forgot to include the declaration of the random generator.

Comment: @AdamGrolli: Also, I missed that it was VB. I have converted it now.

Comment: No sweat. This seems to work well. Had to switch hex to bin converters to get an accurate read. Came out 52 to 52. Just as described. It really is amazing what you guys can do.

Comment: Ok so by chance do you know how to make the last 22 bits into a hash/checksum for the first 106? That would complete the string generation process.

Comment: You would pad it with zeroes to 112 bits, so there is whole bytes to work with, then you can create a hash using something like MD5 or SHA-1. The hash code will be larger than 22 bits, so you can just take the first 22 bits of it. The hash code is uniform, so cutting it down doesn't break it, it only increases the risk for hash collisions.

Comment: anyway I can have you add that to the existing? or write it out somewhere? Ive only been doing this for 3 weeks.. what seems to take you and others just minutes take me days lol. I appreciate it greatly

Comment: @AdamGrolli: Got some time over, so I whipped up an example for adding a hash code.

Comment: So the last line "b.Substring(0, 26) + BitConverter.ToString(hash, 0, 3).Replace("-", String.Empty)" it throws an error pointing to the 3 after (hash, 0,3) error reads - Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length. Im gonna go home and play more with this just figured Id ask you.  is there a way to message you on here?

Comment: @AdamGrolli: I have tested the code so I know that it works. Print out the length of `hash` to try to pinpoint the problem. The length should be 20.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a list with an equal number of 0s and 1s and then sort it with an array of random keys:

```
Sub Main()
    ' Start with a list of 53 0's and 1's
    Dim bitsList = New List(Of Integer)
    For i = 1 To 53
        bitsList.Add(1)
        bitsList.Add(0)
    Next
    Dim bits = bitsList.ToArray()
    ' Create list of random keys
    Dim keys = New List(Of Integer)
    Dim rand = New Random()
    For i = 1 To bits.Count
        keys.Add(rand.Next())
    Next
    ' Sort bits by random keys
    Array.Sort(keys.ToArray(), bits)
    ' Create hex string
    Dim s = ""
    For i = 1 To bits.Length - 4 Step 4
        Dim digit = bits(i + 3) * 8 + bits(i + 2) * 4 + bits(i + 1) * 2 + bits(i)
        s = s + Hex(digit)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(s)
End Sub
```

Comment: So I tested yours and it generates, however it averages about 40-43 zeros and 25-28 ones. If you have a way to tweak this, awesome otherwise I will be toying with it and hopefully set it

Comment: My apologies yours works spot on as well. Thank you I will use both methods given.